# Setting up a search crawler for a remote file server

Tags: 2013, search, crawl, file-shares

We have a SharePoint Server 2013 farm and a file server at a **different location**. We want to crawl the file server, in order to provide index data to the SharePoint search. The search range has been extended accordingly, and searching works fine. However there is way too much traffic between farm and file server when the crawler is indexing the file share.

What is the recommended setup for this kind of delocalization ?
It seems to be necessary to set up the crawler at the site where the file server is, and either access the index remotely, or transmit just the indexing results to the farm site.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to crawl the content in place or replicate the content to a server closer to your Crawler. Solutions like DFS and others can help. You could also stand up a new crawler, but DFS is a much easier solution. You can use Server Name Mapping to ensure that the File Server route is reflected correctly in the Search Results.

Comment: Since I have a similar request now: Can I assume that having a farm in e.g. London and an additional Search Server in e.g. Tokyo which crawls a file server in Tokyo and only transfers the index information back to my farm in London is not a supported / possible option? THX

Comment: We call that a "stretched farm" it is only supported if you can ensure network performance and latency requirements are sufficient for database access. Generally, it is not advisable. Hence why we often replicate the content instead.